# Eclipse delete whitespace shortcut

Tags: eclipse

I am always deleting blocks of whitespace from code.  Instead of ctrl-shift-arrow-keying around, I am looking for a way to delete the current whitespace block under the cursor in eclipse.

e.g. say my code is:

```
    <macrodef name="execute-step">
        <attribute name="plugins" />
        <attribute name="step" />
        <sequential>   |
            <sleep-if-required sleep-time-property-name="sleep-before-@{step}"/>
```

(with the pipe "|" being my cursor).  It would be nice to hit a shortcut key to pull out that block of whitespace, to give:

```
    <macrodef name="execute-step">
        <attribute name="plugins" />
        <attribute name="step" />
        <sequential>|<sleep-if-required sleep-time-property-name="sleep-before-@{step}"/>
```

(Again, pipe "|" shows cursor position after whitespace is removed.)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could do a control find-replace `\n` and `\s` and `\t` and `\r` and replace them with nothing in between the two blocks of code.

Comment: How much `Ctrl + Alt + J` (join lines) would help you?

Answer (score -1):

There is no such functionality in Eclipse itself or in any Eclipse plugin that I'm aware of. However, the one that comes closest would probably be [AnyEdit](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/anyedit/). Its ability to automatically remove whitespace from the ends of lines should take care of the whitespace in front of your cursor in your example. It's open source, so you could always dive into it and add the feature yourself (remember to share it with AnyEdit so the rest of us benefit, too!).

If that's not your thing, you could easily use a third-party app to invoke the appropriate macro for you to delete the whitespace. If you prefer to use keyboard shortcuts, you could try (assuming Windows) something like [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), or, if you prefer using your mouse, one of my favourite apps ever (too bad its Ubuntu equivalents aren't anywhere near as good!) is [StrokeIt](http://www.tcbmi.com/strokeit/), which lets you use custom mouse gestures to do... well, just about anything.

The macro you're looking for would be something like this:

<kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>Del</kbd>

The first key will move to the *end of the non-whitespace text* in the line, i.e. in your example it will actually move left. The next two will select to the *start of the non-whitespace text* in the following line, so then you can just delete the whitespace between those two lines. Obviously this will only work if there aren't any empty lines in-between.

Bind your macro to an available keyboard combination or to a mouse gesture and away you go.

Comment: A comment explaining the downvote would've been appreciated... My answer isn't _wrong_, and, given that I don't think the feature the OP is asking for exists, nearly four years later, it's still the closest thing I know of to do what was asked for.